# SQL Server what is the current ORM best case technology for .Net?

Tags: .net, sql-server, nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

I'm considering using NHibernate as a ORM layer for my application.

However, Entity Framework appears to be touted as the Current Big Thing in ORM for .Net, and appears to stomp on the Linq for SQL strategy that MS were pushing only a few years ago.

The question is really, what's the best choice for ORM / SQL Server in .Net solutions currently?

Deciding factors are:

- Developer support
- Widely used
- Clean syntax
- Good tools
- Stability

Comment: NHibernate & Lightspeed are the two best ORM's for .NET, EF4.0 is still playing catchup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nhibernate, entity framework, active records or linq2sql ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm asking myself the same question and I'm looking at either : -

MyBatis.NET http://www.mybatis.org/dotnet.html  or

nHibernate http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx

MyBatis.NET looks good if you are after more of a data mapper and are happy to do a bit of SQL.

nHibernate still looks like the best and most mature ORM but there's a bigger learning curve and finding obscure errors is not fun.